# Dozer mapping for complex objects

Tags: java, converters, dozer

I have 2 POJOs as shown below :

```
package com.main.java.src;

    public class SourceObj {
    
    protected String name;
    ...
    ...
    10 String objects
    
    protected Addresses addresses; 
    
    ...
    ...
    getter and setter for all fields
    
    }

package com.java.main.src;

    public class Addresses {
     protected List<Address> address;
    ...
    getters and setters
    }

package com.main.java.src;

    public class Address {
       protected String city;
    
       protected List<Contact> contact;
    
    ...
    
    getters & setters
    }

package com.main.java.dest;

    public class DestObj {
    
    protected String name;
    ...
    ...
    10 String objects
    
    protected Addresses addresses; 
    
    ...
    ...
    getter and setter for all fields
    
    }
    
package com.main.java.dest;

    public class Addresses {
     protected List<Address> address;
    ...
    getters and setters
    }
    
package com.main.java.dest;

    public class Address {
       protected String city;
    
       protected List<Contact> contact;
    
    ...
    
    getters & setters
    }
```

Now I have the dozer-configuration.xml as follows:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <mappings xmlns="http://dozer.sourceforge.net" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://dozer.sourceforge.net http://dozer.sourceforge.net/schema/beanmapping.xsd">
        <configuration>
            <stop-on-errors>true</stop-on-errors>
            <trim-strings>true</trim-strings>
            <relationship-type>non-cumulative</relationship-type>       
        </configuration>
        
        <mapping>
            <class-a>com.main.java.src.SourceObj</class-a>
            <class-b>com.main.java.dest.DestObj</class-b>
            <field>
                <a>addresses.address</a>
                <b>addresses.address</b>
                <a-hint>com.main.java.src.Address</a-hint>
                <b-hint>com.main.java.dest.Address</b-hint>
            <field> 
        </mapping>
    </mappings>
```

Now the above mapping copies fields like name from SourceObj to DestObj, but not able to map List of Address from src package to List of Address of dest package. Again inside Address object, there is a list of Contact object.

One solution I found is to write a custom converter which will copy primitive field values one by one and then all objects from one list to another destination list.

But I am looking for a solution in dozer-configuration.xml.

After the above xml mappings, I am getting below exception:

```
MapId: null
  Type: null
  Source parent class: com.main.java.src.SourceObj
  Source field name: addresses.address
  Source field type: class java.util.ArrayList
  Source field value: [com.main.java.src.Address@1b65d51d]
  Dest parent class: com.main.java.dest.DestObj
  Dest field name: addresses.address
  Dest field type: java.util.List

java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.dozer.util.ReflectionUtils.invoke(ReflectionUtils.java:329) ~[dozer-5.5.1.jar:?]
    at org.dozer.propertydescriptor.GetterSetterPropertyDescriptor.writeDeepDestinationValue(GetterSetterPropertyDescriptor.java:268) ~[dozer-5.5.1.jar:?]
    at org.dozer.propertydescriptor.GetterSetterPropertyDescriptor.setPropertyValue(GetterSetterPropertyDescriptor.java:96) ~[dozer-5.5.1.jar:?]
    at org.dozer.fieldmap.FieldMap.writeDestValue(FieldMap.java:96) ~[dozer-5.5.1.jar:?]
    at org.dozer.MappingProcessor.writeDestinationValue(MappingProcessor.java:939) ~[dozer-5.5.1.jar:?]
    at org.dozer.MappingProcessor.mapFromFieldMap(MappingProcessor.java:368) ~[dozer-5.5.1.jar:?]
    at org.dozer.MappingProcessor.mapField(MappingProcessor.java:307) [dozer-5.5.1.jar:?]
    at org.dozer.MappingProcessor.map(MappingProcessor.java:267) [dozer-5.5.1.jar:?]
    at org.dozer.MappingProcessor.mapToDestObject(MappingProcessor.java:216) [dozer-5.5.1.jar:?]
    at org.dozer.MappingProcessor.createByCreationDirectiveAndMap(MappingProcessor.java:196) [dozer-5.5.1.jar:?]
    at org.dozer.MappingProcessor.mapGeneral(MappingProcessor.java:170) [dozer-5.5.1.jar:?]
    at org.dozer.MappingProcessor.map(MappingProcessor.java:104) [dozer-5.5.1.jar:?]
    at org.dozer.MappingProcessor.map(MappingProcessor.java:99) [dozer-5.5.1.jar:?]
    at org.dozer.DozerBeanMapper.map(DozerBeanMapper.java:120) [dozer-5.5.1.jar:?]
```

What could be the solution for this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer after much trial and error. Please refer the below solution.

```
<mapping>
  <class-a>com.java.main.src.SourceObj</class-a>
  <class-b>com.java.main.dest.DestObj</class-b>
  <field>><!-- java.util.List to java.util.List -->
     <a is-accessible="true">addresses.address</a>
     <b is-accessible="true">addresses.address</b>
     <a-hint>com.java.main.src.Address</a-hint>
     <b-hint>com.java.main.dest.Address</b-hint>
  </field>
</mapping>

<mapping>
  <class-a>com.java.main.src.Address</class-a>
  <class-b>com.java.main.dest.Address</class-b>
  <field>
     <a get-method="isIsPrimaryAddress">isIsPrimaryAddress</a>
     <b get-method="isIsPrimaryAddress">isIsPrimaryAddress</b>     
  </field>
</mapping>
```

If for Address object, the getter method is not defined as getFieldName, in that case you need to map as we have mapped isIsPrimaryAddress as shown above. All the other fields names have same names in both Address objects, and so the values will be copied automatically.

Comment: Offtopic: Dozer is inefficient since it's based on Reflection API. I suggest you to migrate to modern mapping tools like [Orika](https://orika-mapper.github.io/orika-docs/) or [MapStruct](https://mapstruct.org/)

Comment: Yup we are thinking to migrate to MapStruct

Answer (score 0):

Dozer will map anything with the same name and type automatically. When the fields you want to map have different names, you must explicitly tell Dozer in the mapping which fields to map to each other. 
In the question above, the AddressSrc and AddressDest are fields with different names. Therefore, you must explicitly tell Dozer to map those two fields to each other.

```
<mapping>
    <class-a>SourceObj</class-a>
    <class-b>DestObj</class-b>    
    <field>
        <a>addressesSrc</a>
        <b set-method="customSetMethodName">addressesDest</b>
    </field>  
</mapping>
```

You may need additional mapping instructions to get the result you ultimately want. However, this is the missing mapping piece you need to get Dozer to map these two fields since they have different names.

Comment: Actually name of both the fields is addresses but the package names are different. What should be done in this case?

Comment: Please provide a more accurate example representation (i.e. matching field names  and types where they match, etc)
Also, please provide more detail on the collection result, i.e. are the object in the result collection the correct type? And the correct number? What is mapped and what isnt?

Comment: Hi John, I have edited the code for better representation. Name of member variables for SourceObj and DestObj are same, but they are of different types i.e. Addresses in SourceObj is from package com.java.main.src and in DestObj from com.java.main.dest. Again they contain list of Address objects. The one type of Address object is com.java.main.src.Address and other being com.java.main.dest.Address. The Contact class is also of 2 types com.java.main.src.Contact and com.java.main.dest.Contact. Please advise with dozer mappings.

Comment: Thanks... very helpful as is the stacktrace. Basically, the stacktrace indicates that there is a missing/misnamed setter somewhere.  Dozer expects getter/setter methods to follow convention. In the case that they dont, you can specify a customer getter or setter name for any field in the mapping. I've updated the answer to show how.

Comment: Hi John, I debugged the code, while debugging i see the control is going in setter method of Addresses class, but the list of Address objects is null. I also tried using custom setter method, but that also has the same problem.

Comment: Ah, so the NPE is happening in the setter method?  Can you post the setter method that is being called here?